# Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i have been trying to make a discord bot, when a user gets kicked (by a staff member) it will send a embed to a log channel but it keeps throwing errors

```js
Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
```

here is my code:

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setAuthor(message.author.tag,message.author.avatarURL())
.setFooter("Made by frenchee1607")
.addField("Moderation:", "kick")
.addField("Mutee:", member.user.username)
.addField("Moderator:", message.author.username)
.addField("Reason:", reason)
.addField("Date:", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())
let Channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "mods-chat-logger");        
if (Channel) {
    Channel.send(message)
} else {
    message.channel.send("Error sending embed to <#735829837306003456>");
}
```

I have tried doing

```js
client.channels.cache.get("735829837306003456")
```

but even this wont work. I have asked some of my friend and even they dont know, if anyone can help I would be very grateful!

(I should also say that i am new to programming)

Comment: The error means that you are reading the property `channels` from an `undefined` value. You try to read `channels` from `client`, so `client` is `undefined`. (Which seems to be correct. Nowhere in your code do you define what `client` is.

Comment: @Ivar this is only part of the code the rest has nothing to do with the embed and sending it to the specified channel, but i did define the client ```const { client } = require("../index.js");``` is what it says (im pretty sure its not the problem but if it is tell me). Thanks for ur comment!

Comment: @frenchee1607 you have to drop more code. Ivar is correct in what he says and you need watch when you initialized the value of "client" and see why it comes as undefined

Comment: @Deian oh my bad should I add my the entirety of my code? (tho keep in mind some of it was a mix of tutorials and myself)

Comment: @frenchee1607 no, you should debug your code :)

Comment: @Deian lmao, yes. I might do it tomorrow with a fresh mind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you run in your terminal npm view discord.js version and npm view discord.js-commando version? What numbers do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much, but I think this is how you should do it.

Change the following

```
let Channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "mods-chat-logger");
```

to this (if you have Discord.js v12):

```
let Channel = message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "mods-chat-logger");
```

or this (if you have Discord.js v11):

```
let Channel = message.client.channels.find("name", "mods-chat-logger");
```